# Xamarin.Forms: "InitializeComponent does not exist" when cloning from Github

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms PCL Project (both iOS and Android). I can build it perfectly in my local repo. However, if I clone or download the same up-to-date code from Github, I got the error *"InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context"*

My setup is:

- Xamarin.Forms PCL Project
- Xamarin.Forms 1.5.0.6446
- Xamarin Studio 5.9.7 (build 9)
- Mac OS X
- My gitignore file: https://gist.github.com/NamXH/00690ea72a426d9f0383

I am aware that there are some known bugs with *"InitializeComponent does not exist"* in a Shared Project or Visual Studio. However, I think mine is different.

There's another weird situation: If I update Xamarin.Forms packages to a newer version, the project can be built normally. However, if I **discard** all the changes (by checking out the commit before updating), I got the *InitializeComponent* error. When I checkout the latest commit (with the new packages changes), it can be built again. Everything is done locally in this situation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is yours different exactly? In your .gtignore file, you have a "*.designer.cs" which means that the auto-generated files will not be in github which also means that you'd have to through each .xaml file and save it again to generate those files. Try committing your designer.cs files and see if that compiles.

Comment: Copy the entire solution folder as it builds, then diff the building copy to the non-building one, find  suspicious changes, modify them by hand in the non-building copy, rinse and repeat until root cause is found. Then submit a bug (if any) in Xamarin's bugzilla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The issue is I use Github client for Mac and for some reasons the client does not detect all the changes in the **packages** folder. I have to use the *git add* command in the console to add the missing files (mostly dll files).

In short, every time I update packages, I have to use git commands in the console to add new changes.